# Check constraint references another column in same table

Tags: sql-server, constraint, ddl, check-constraints

I have this table but check constraint is throwing me an error:

> Column CHECK constraint for column 'MedicamentRegulated' references another column, table 'Medicaments'.

I've seen this as allowed in SQL Server but I don't know why it doesn't work :/

```
CREATE TABLE Medicaments (
MedicamentID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(50),
DateValidity DATE,
MedicamentRegulated BIT CHECK((MedicamentRegulated = 1 AND DateValidity IS NOT NULL) 
  OR MedicamentRegulated = 0)
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax you are using is for a column-level constraint, so it can only apply to the column it is attached to... try naming your constraints at the table level instead (this also <s>allows</s> encourages you to give your constraints meaningful names instead of the terrible system defaults):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Medicaments -- always use schema*
(
  MedicamentID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  DateValidity DATE,
  MedicamentRegulated BIT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_Med PRIMARY KEY (MedicamentID),
  CONSTRAINT ck_Med_reg CHECK
  (
    (MedicamentRegulated = 1 AND DateValidity IS NOT NULL) 
    OR MedicamentRegulated = 0
  )
);
```

*see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).